# Why is Rails treating request as JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rest, http

Why is Rails 4.2.0.beta2 treating this request as JSON?

request:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/messages/eb89135
```

log:

```
Processing by MessagesController#show as JSON
```

response:

```
{"message":{...}}
```

Here are the relevant bits of my app:

```
# messages#show

  def show

    @message = Message.find_by_shortlink(params[:shortlink])

    @message

  end

# Gemfile
  source 'https://rubygems.org'

  ruby '2.1.2'

  gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'v4.2.0.beta2'
  gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'haml'
```

GET requests from a web browser are also treated as JSON.

Using [URL].html works as expected from the browser and CURL, but I'd like to avoid having to use the extension and let Rails sort out the content type based on the provided headers.

I just spun up a new Rails 4.2.0 app as a sanity check and the request/response act as expected.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Are you setting the default response in your routes file?

Comment: Yes - that was it! Please submit that as an answer and I'd be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you aren't setting the default response format in your routes file.